# Excel get cell value which is NOT Match in a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: screen shot]

I would like to search `C2:I2` which is the cell value NOT equal to `"=No="`, which is `"ABC"`, and the formula I would like to store in `A2`.

I was able to look for some formula which works with `MATCH()`, but I would like to get `NOT MATCH`.

Can anyone can help in this?

Comment: sorry for the wrong place, I saw similar Excel question asking here. So I posted my question here. Sorry for this. What is the Excel tag means in stackoverflow is it Excel VBA?

Comment: You can click the tag and check out the questions located there

Comment: It is true that some questions can or could be answered with either formula or VBA. This is sometimes tricky to know wether to post your question. Don't worry, if needed, your question will be migrated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
{=INDEX(C2:I2,MATCH(TRUE,C2:I2<>"=NO=",0))}
```

This is an array formula you should validate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Can you explain more about this formula means? 
Are you sure is C2:I2<>"A" ? I need not equal to =NO=. And I tried with your formula. It does not work as well.

Comment: sorry. I made my test with only A and B (because "=" is a pain to handle in an Excel cell). Btw, I also corrected because I forgot to translate the `TRUE` statement.

Comment: the formula is trying to Match within an array if any of the cell is different from "=NO=" by checking if it returns TRUE

Comment: Thank JMax. This is the first time I used array formula, I didn't notice that I shouldn't include the {} :p Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I didn't add that you had to remove the {}

Answer (score 4):

Here's a non-array suggestion:

[image]

And here is the formula you can copy paste:

`=LOOKUP(2, 1/($C$2:$J$2<>"=No="), $C$2:$J$2)`